# From business methods to Command classes

Tags: java, architecture

To prevent long, procedural business classes like e.g. `BookService` with many, many methods that does the same, we decided to make a command class instead of each method - or set of similar methods. For example, if `BookService` has the following method:

```
Book createBook(String name, String author, String description) {
    // business code
    db.store(book);
    return book;
}
```

We have 3 things here

- mandatory fields (`name`, `author`)
- optional field (`description`)
- usage of infrastructure (`db`)

After replacement, we have the following:

```
Book createBook(String name, String author) {
    return new CreateBookCmd(db).withName(name).withAuthor(author);
}
```

and the command class is:

```
public class CreateBookCmd() implements Cmd {
    public CreateBookCmd(Db db) {this.db=db;}
    public CreateBookCmd withName(String name) {this.name=name; return this;}
    public CreateBookCmd withAuthor(String author) {this.author=author; return this;}
    public CreateBookCmd withDescription(String description) {this.description=description; return this;}

    public Book execute() {
         // validate inputs
         // business code
         db.store(book);
         return book;
    }
}
```

Things I like:

- factory method in original class specifies only mandatory arguments, others are called with fluent interface: `bookManager.createBook("A", "B").withDescription("C").execute();`
- Business code is encapsulated in one class.

Things I don't like:

- without a factory there is no way to figure which property is mandatory in compile-time.
- need to inject infrastructure into business class.

Question:

- Wouldn't it be better if command class has mandatory arguments in constructor?
- Maybe its better to remove all args from ctor and inject infrastructure as well using `with` methods?
- Is there a way to force compile-time check if all required arguments are set prior to calling exec()

Somehow it bothers me that something in passed in constructor and something is passes using setters or with-methods.

Comment: Constructor parameters are a better fit for your requirements. I don't know what you mean by "infrastructure".

Comment: @FrankHileman infrastructure == objects that are not related to business, but are used to e.g. store data to external storage. I dont know why, but I dont like to mix what I call "infrastructure" with the business.

Comment: What you are doing is a well known pattern called CQRS, go research the pattern and you could find plenty of good documentation and examples online